# Manage Dynamic fields on page - Postgres and MongoDB

Tags: java, sql, angularjs, mongodb, postgresql

I'm using MongoDB and PostgreSQL as database and angularJS for UI in my application. There is a requirement that some fields (columns) may be added dynamically on pages so it's DOM definition will be taken from user with required attributes when he adds this field in the system for some page.

Also, the user should be able to disable the existing fields which are fixed on page. (Such fields will have columns in RDBMS i.e. Postgres here)

In Postgres, RDBMS should be predefined so I believe it might not be used for fulfilling my requirement though not impossible with that. The only issue which I might face is the performance issue. We have to deal with lacs of data here and as of now, I'm going to use Postgres for storing data. MongoDB allows to have dynamic columns but data is in Postgres. Also, Postgres is used as primary database in my application and MongoDB is used for reports where lacs of data when retrieved or processed, it'd take less time than Postgres.

How should I proceed now? What approaches can be taken to fulfill my requirements stated above? Can someone explain to me what should I do here?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem you are willing to use Mongo, so my 2 suggestions would be:

Suggestion 1: You could have a table in Postgres that describes the json that would be stored in Mongo. Just make is a long text or a blob.

Suggestion 2: Don't store the whole json document in Postgres, instead parse the fields and store them in a key-value table in Postgres